# Hint for the limit

Tags: limits

In the following limit.

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{[\ln (1+x)-\ln 2](3\cdot4^{x-1}-3x)}{\left[(7+x)^\frac{1}{3}-(1+3x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right]\sin(x-1)}$$

Can anybody provide me a hint to solve as I am not getting anything because of  $0$.$0$/$0.0$ indeterminancy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Let $x-1=2h$

$$=3\ln2\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)}{\sqrt{8+2h}-\sqrt{6h+4}}\cdot\dfrac{4^{2h}-(2h+1)}{\sin2h}$$

$$=\dfrac{3\ln2}2\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)}h\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\sin2h}{2h}}\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0}(\sqrt{8+2h}-\sqrt{6h+4})}\cdot  \lim_{h\to0}(4^{2h}-(2h+1))$$

Comment: Why you have only taken 2h . Can we take anything else instead of it.

Comment: @J.Doe, Yes you could. I did that to find $$\ln(1+1+2h)=\ln2+\ln(1+h)$$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Divide the top and bottom by $(x-1)(x-1)$ and use definition of derivative for $3$ functions at $x = 1$. The other quotien is $\dfrac{\sin(x-1)}{x-1} \to 1$ as $x \to 1$. Can you identify the $3$ related functions?

Comment: I have got for ln(1+x) and sin(x-1) , but what about others

Comment: $f(x) = \ln(1+x), g(x) = 3\times 4^{x-1} - 3x, h(x) = (7+x)^{1/3} - (1+3x)^{1/2}$.

Comment: From this I am not getting the answer . The anser given in my book is (-9/4)$ln(4/e)$

Comment: You will have to take derivative of those functions at $x = 1$ and multiply them. That's why I put it as a hint, and I like for you to work out the details since I don't want to write every thing down for you because it seems like this is a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use Taylor series built around $x=1$ $$\sqrt[3]{x+7}=2+\frac{x-1}{12} +O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ $$\sqrt[2]{1+3x}=2+\frac{3 (x-1)}{4}+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ $$\sqrt[3]{x+7}-\sqrt[2]{1+3x}=-\frac{2 (x-1)}{3} +O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ $$\log(1+x)-\log(2)=\frac{x-1}{2} +O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ $$3  \times 4^{x-1}=3\times e^{(x-1)\log(4)}=3+3  \log (4)(x-1) +O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ $$3  \times 4^{x-1}-3x= 3( \log (4)-1)(x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$

$$\frac{[\ln (1+x)-\ln 2](3\cdot4^{x-1}-3x)}{\left[(7+x)^\frac{1}{3}-(1+3x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \right]}=-\frac{9}{4} ( \log (4)-1) (x-1)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$

I am sure sure that you can finish easily from here.